# Get my checked out items via core service API

Tags: core-service

Here's how I'm trying to do this, but I find it includes items that are checked out to "tcm:0-0-0" as well as my user ID.

```
$filter = New-Object Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.RepositoryLocalObjectsFilterData;
$lockUserLink = New-Object Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.LinkToUserData
$lockUserLink.IdRef = $UserId
$filter.LockUser = $lockUserLink
$client.GetSystemWideList($filter)
```

Is this a defect in my code or a product defect (or an undocumented feature)?

Comment: As an admin you have rights to see everything of all users, but when you specify the lockuser I would indeed expect that it would filter those results. If it doesn't then I would report that as a defect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue has been confirmed as a defect.  RepositoryLocalObjectsFilterData.LockUser  should return only the checked-out items of the user executing it.   It does not.   It should get fixed in the next release.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to specify the `LockUser`. As per documentation: `As per current implementation if ItemIds is set then it returns those items constrained by the filter. Otherwise it returns items that are checked out, either by the current user if LockUser is not set, or by the user specified in LockUser condition, constrained by the rest of the filter condition.`

Try to not specify the `LockUser`, but I agree with you, it should work like this as well, but it goes the different code path in case `LockUser` is set, so it might be a bug.

It also might work differently if you are an admin.

Comment: perhaps it is because I am an admin... I get exactly the same count as when specifying the lock user. It tells me there are 2048 items checked out, but if I loop through and inspect those that have the lock user actually set to my id, it's 5. that's a few orders of magnitude :)

Comment: I would report it as a bug, I guess it should be either fixed or documented